# How can i make VPN Tunnel Between GCP Cloud VPN and my PC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

I'm connected to a corporate network. I want to establish a VPN Tunnel Between my PC and GCP Cloud VPN.
Can someone guide me related to this that what type of VPN should I use? I mean should I use HA VPN or Static VPN or Dynamic VPN and how? or an refer any video or website link. Help is appreciated. Peace!

Comment: This configuration is strange. Why do you need this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Edit your question and clarify what your current configuration is. Cloud VPN is a site-to-site VPN and not a remote access VPN. This means deploying a supported router in your home network. I use WireGuard which is easy to deploy to connect my desktop to GCP. Another option is OpenVPN.

Answer (score 1):

The VPN type could depend on what you need.

[HA VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#ha-vpn):

> HA VPN is a high-availability (HA) Cloud VPN solution that lets you
> securely connect your on-premises network to your VPC network through
> an IPsec VPN connection in a single region. HA VPN provides an SLA of
> 99.99% service availability.

[Classic VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#classic-vpn):

> In contrast, Classic VPN gateways have a single interface, a single
> external IP address, and support tunnels that use dynamic (BGP) or
> static routing (policy-based or route-based). They provide an SLA of
> 99.9% service availability.

[Dynamic routing](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/choosing-networks-routing#dynamic-routing)

> Dynamic routing uses a Cloud Router to automatically manage the
> exchange of routes by using BGP. A BGP interface on a Cloud Router in
> the same region as the corresponding Cloud VPN tunnel manages this
> exchange. The Cloud Router adds and removes routes without requiring
> that the tunnel be deleted and re-created.

[Static routing](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/choosing-networks-routing#static-routing)

> Classic VPN tunnels support policy-based and route-based static
> routing options. Consider a static routing option only if you cannot
> use dynamic (BGP) routing or HA VPN.
>
> Policy-based routing. Local IP ranges (left side) and remote IP ranges
> (right side) are defined as part of the tunnel creation process.
>
> Route-based VPN. When you use the Google Cloud Console to create a
> route-based VPN, you only specify a list of remote IP ranges. Those
> ranges are used only to create routes in your VPC network to peer
> resources.

Consider to be aware of traffic selectors recommendations [Routing options and traffic selectors](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/choosing-networks-routing#ts-tun-routing)

However, by the time being the best option is to [create an HA VPN gateway to a peer VPN gateway](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn) but this will require a Router located on on-premises. Classic VPN with static and dynamic routing will be deprecated on October 31, 2021. But you can create them following [how-to-guides](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to) or following a different process using [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs-category/vpn-setup-examples/) within your VPN.